# Calculating new averages

Tags: self-study, mean

I'm studying for a midterm in my basic stats course and came across a question that I'm confused with how it's solved.

---

A manager at a local gas bar has 13 staff members. The average hourly wage for
the employees is `$10.55` per hour. One experienced employee, who was making `$12.50`
per hour, quit because they were offered a better job. They were replaced with two
employees, each getting a starting wage of `$9.00` per hour. What is the new average
hourly wage for the employees at the gas bar?

---

The way I attempted to solve this was:

$\frac{(12*10.55) - 12.5 + (9*2)}{13} = \$10.16$

However it's not one of the possible choices:

```
(A) $10.97 
(B) $10.19 
(C) $10.28 
(D) $10.82 
(E) $10.68
```

Can anyone point out what I did incorrectly?

---

As pointed out in the answers section I miss calculated N. The formula should be:

$\frac{(13*10.55)-12.5+(9*2)}{14} = \$10.19$

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be a matter of interpretation but as I read it the intent is that the situation in the question starts with 13 staff members, rather than 12, and presumably ends up with 14 rather than 13.

Reassuringly, that would then give a result that matches one of the answers.